# Visual Studio error - Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-job

I have an .exe that we are trying to run automatically. The application, searches a couple databases, and extract some info, then places them into an excel file, which it then drops on the server and then emails.

The app was made in VS 2010.

When the user (Admin account) runs the .exe it will run properly, creating the excel file, dropping it on the server, and then emailing the file without any errors. This is a 64 bit windows 2008 server.

The issue arrises once we put it on a SQL job. We tried this two ways, one using an SSIS package that runs the .exe, and two, using the command line to run the .exe. Both ways fail. It is being run by the same Admin user account. But somewhere in the file, I believe when it drops the file on the local server, it errors out. This is a SQL Server 2008 Job.

I have the app send me an email with the error information but I cannot walkthrough the code to find the exact line because when I do a walkthough it works properly, I only get this error when triggering the .exe from the SQL job. 
The error i recieve is - "executable errored out with exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

What could be causing this error?

Comment: probably you got more details from this error. Check if you have some "Details" or "View More" options from this given error. (ya, that amout of useless text)

Comment: I am having difficulty getting anyting else from the error. All I have is what it emails me (which is the whole VS eror message which is attached). As I can't walkthrough the code and find the error manually as it runs normally when not through the SQL Job. Ideas on how to get a more detailed error message? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this to work, I created this folder path - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop . I then put the .exe and .config file in that path. Edit the SQL job to point to that path to run the .exe and it will run properly. (Note, I also had that be the location where the excel sheet is dropped).